# Can we use SAML2 & OpenId Connect together in single azure custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to add both SAML2 and OpenId Connect together for logging in Azure B2C Custom Policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - just a matter of configuring the different elements in the policy.

Essentially, this uses federation. This federation allows your users to sign in with their existing social or enterprise identities.

[OIDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect-technical-profile).

[SAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-technical-profile).

Comment: will SSO work for both SAML and OIDC in azure ad b2c?

Comment: Yes it will - no problems.